# Compiling with Android 4.X but supporting API Level 9

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

I'm working on an application which uses ActionBarSherlock. As it's [documentation](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) points out:

> [...] the library requires that **both it and your project are
>   compiled with Android 4.0 or newer.** The project also requires that
>   you are compiling with JDK 1.6 in both your editor and any build
>   systems that you may be using.

So, that means I'll compile my application (and the library) against Android 4.X but in my Manifest, I declare that I'm targeting (e.g.) API Level 9.

This all works fine and well but there is something that disturbs me. From the [FAQ](http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html):

> **What API level should I target in my manifest when using the library?**
>
> Targetting API level 11 or newer is required as it will cause Android
>   to automatically add the native action bar when run on newer devices.
>   Since you will be compiling against new APIs but your app will likely
>   be run on devices with older versions of Android **extra care must be
>   taken to either avoid using or properly check and call any methods
>   that were introduced after your minimum SDK version.**

That means, that I'll have to *manually* check every method call, so I don't use any that are not available in my targeted API Level (9 in my case)? This sounds wrong to me.

Is there a way to tell my IDE (IntelliJ), that I'm only using the API Level 9 (so I don't get any auto-completion for non-existing methods/classes and don't use them by accident) and then choose to compile it against another Android version?

Or can I use some automated checks (which run at compile time) to check for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ADT's lint feature should take care of this by warning when API calls are being made for the wrong API version.

You should be compiling both ABS and your project with the latest SDK available (at present, 4.1). Your manifest should have a `targetSdkVersion` as high as possible (ideally matching your compilation SDK) and your `minSdkVersion` should be set to the lowest version you support.

Lint is partially integrated with IntelliJ IDEA and is also available as a command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

You temporarily set your target SDK to the various lower ones and debug with it.  Your final build then is with the latest SDK.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant manual by looking up each call and checking.  I don't think it does what you want automatically.  That's a good idea for a future ADT update but I don't think it's available currently.  But I'm not sure!

Answer (score 0):

Set a Build target similar to that you have mentioned in your manifest.

Comment: setting a Build target is different then setting a target SDK version. It also doesn't require any changes in the manifest. I know at least in eclipse changing the build target will fix all the error messages. You probably also want to include a lower minSdkVersion as well are your targetSdkVersion, so that it will be available form the minSdkVersion on the Play store.

Answer (score 0):

as always , you should set the targetSdk to the maximum available on both the manifest and the project.properties file (as recommended by google on one of their videos) , so that the ADT&SDK would be able to optimize the ADK accordingly.

set the minSdk to the one that you wish to support your app from , and let Lint to tell you if there are any problems in case you use too-new-features.